# How to move articles to a new website without problems with SEO or rewriting?

Tags: seo, search-engines, copyright, articles

How do you do.
My old website was based on uCoz. It was desined badly and was based on uCoz free domain. I decided to create the new site version myself, going to another hosting and changing the design. But the old website had got some good articles. I've heard that search engines will be able to decide that the articles were stolen if I just copy them. I don't want to use rewriting. Is it posible to move them without a risk for SEO? 
*Excuse my English.*

Comment: What you're referring to is "duplicate content". You can solve this by taking the old site down so that the articles are only on the new site. Does that suit your purposes?